# Does it matter for the security of AES how the byte array is encoded in C#?

Tags: c#, aes

I have a byte array that was encrypted using AES with the pass phrase encrypted using SHA-256.
Everything works perfect, but I'm wondering about the last part where I have to encode the byte array that I get as a result of the encryption.
Does it matter, for the robustness of the end result how the byte array is encrypted, Base64, conversion to hexadecimal values, something else?

Logically speaking, it doesn't matter since there really aren't that much encoding methods and most of the time the most obvious one, Base64, is used. 
But since I'm not that well versed with cryptography I just want to make sure.

Take a byte array as an example (random array of bytes as an example):

```
    [0] 182 
    [1] 238 
    [2] 54
    [3] 24  
    [4] 69  
    [5] 224 
    [6] 105 
    [7] 13  
    [8] 5   
    [9] 52  
    [10]112 
    [11]71  
    [12]250 
    [13]163 
    [14]234 
    [15]234
```

This gives a possible result in Base64 (random result, does not match above):

```
ou+yUEkilfrGIF3HBH08vu8A==
```

Using BitConvertor to transform it to hexadecimal values gives (random result, does not match above):

```
A2EBCA1945E8BC920532F068D27BAEF1
```

It's simple to convert the above results back to the respective byte array and only then does the hard part start.

Comment: This is not related to AES or security at all, but could be edited into a more general question like _"How can I represent a byte array as a string?"_. And that question exists already, many times.

Comment: "the last part where I have to encode the byte array" - first, be sure that this "last part" is actually required. Many people seem to instinctively add a step to produce a `string` as a result, rather than just stopping when they've got the byte array. If you don't *need* a string, don't do anything further.

Comment: Please ask one question per question, and read [ask] before asking a new one.

Comment: Re: edit. Please see [Kerckhoffs Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle): "A cryptosystem should be secure even if everything about the system, except the key, is public knowledge."

Comment: My apologies CodeCaster, you are right. I shouldn't just add extra followup questions like that, but it seemed silly to add another question given that it is in the end related to my initial one. Also, before my question got answered, I saw it as part of the encryption because I didn't know any better, or at least, I wasn't entirely sure, hence my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it matter, for the robustness of the end result how the byte array is encrypted, Base64, conversion to hexadecimal values, something else?

No, not at all. So long as you're encoding it in a lossless format (which both base64 and hex are) that's fine. *Don't* use something like `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(...)` - that would be lossy and inappropriate. (Don't use `Encoding` at all for this task.)

Just ask yourself whether you could reverse your encoding and get back to the original bytes - if so, you're fine. (And that's true for hex and base64, assuming it's properly implemented.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response. Added one last additional question regarding the end result of the AES cipher.

Comment: @reaper_unique: That's an entirely separate question, about security rather than reliability. Ask it in a separate post.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way. The cipher must produce ciphertext, from which it should not be possible (in practice) to obtain plain text without knowing the key:

```
C=E(K,M) // K is key, M message
```

Now, what you have is ciphertext. Whether you encode it in Base64 or something doesn't really matter, as the cipher already did it's job when it produced the ciphertext. Afterwards you can do anything with it - The cipher already did its job when it produced the cipher text, and it told you if you don't use the original key, it should not be possible to retrieve plain text.

So whatever you do afterwards, e.g. how you encode/decode cipher text, should not really matter.

Comment: Thank you for the additional clarification. Now I'm not sure who to give the check to though... Jon was faster but I dunno he is already a master maybe I should give it to the less fortunate?

Comment: Jon it is. You get one up at least :)